# How to predict a variable or a amount of variables among the time with JavaScript language?

Tags: javascript

I use javascript and I want a function which predicts a variable among the time, like this (I'm only posting a hypothetical example):

```
  net = new brain.recurrent.LSTMTimePrediction()

  net.train([{a:1}])
  net.train([{a:2}])
  net.train([{a:3}])

  console.log(net.run(a))// => 4
```

Second example:

```
  net = new brain.recurrent.LSTMTimePrediction()

  net.train([{a:3}])
  net.train([{a:2}])
  net.train([{a:1}])

  console.log(net.run(a))// => 0
```

Third example:

```
  net = new brain.recurrent.LSTMTimePrediction()

  net.train([{a:1}])
  net.train([{a:2}])
  net.train([{a:4}])

  console.log(net.run(a))// => 8
```

This example obviously generates a function among the points, taking as Y the `a` value and X a counter which identifies all `net.train()`. But I have a problemm, I don't know how to do that, and... how can I implement this???

Comment: So make a [class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/class) with two methods "train" and "run". The train method appears to push items on to an array and the run method does something with that array. Not sure what you are expecting as an answer here.

Comment: Unless there are severe restrictions on your data type and the distinction pattern, you're requiring a fully fledged machine learning algorithm which is itself overly impertinent here.